# Need to create Alerts for AWS IAM Users for MFA, Access key rotation and Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need to create below Alerts on IAM User for MFA, Access key rotation and Login.

1. Create alerts for MFA not enabled and Access Key rotation in 6 month for IAM User.
2. Create alert when some user is not logged in AWS Account for more than 6 months

I googled for above alerts but got nothing. Please provide you inputs on this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS Config Rules to do so:

- iam-user-mfa-enabled -
  Checks whether the AWS Identity and Access Management users have multi-factor authentication (MFA) enabled.
- access-keys-rotated rule -
  Checks whether the active access keys are rotated within the number of days specified in maxAccessKeyAge. The rule is non-compliant if the access keys have not been rotated for more than maxAccessKeyAge number of days.
- iam-user-unused-credentials-check -
  Checks whether your AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) users have passwords or active access keys that have not been used within the specified number of days you provided.

Comment: We can follow this approach but it consuming cost. Is there any other way that we can create alerts.

Comment: You can implement check as a Lambda functions and invoke them with CloudWatch scheduler (i.e. once a day).
If non compliant resource is found, put metric data to CloudWatch metric with Alarm created, or push message to SNS directly from Lambda code

Comment: is there any blog or website to implement these steps one by one?